# Switch coverage in use

Tags: istqb

I have got question below in a mock exam.

> Which of the following series of state transitions below will provide
>   0-switch coverage?

What does switch coverage mean? I have found that this is a part of State Transition Testing and 0-switch(branch coverage) coverage is to execute each loop once, but couldn't see background logic.

*Solution is A, B, E, B, C, F, F, but it isn't important in this case.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chow's switch coverage describes how you cover a state transition model.  A "switch" in this context is a state in between your beginning state and your end state in your traversal of the model.   So 0-switch coverage means that you exercise every direct transition possible in the model.  1-switch coverage means you allow one state between your start and end state.

In a very simple example, say A->B->C->D, 0-switch coverage would be A->B, B->C, and C->D.  1-switch coverage would be A->B->C and B->C->D.